# How can i turn attributes on or off in XML configuration class?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

a part of my XML configuration file looks like this

```
      <Formatting Mode="Format1">
        <FormatterSettings Range="Range1" Restriction="None" Padding="0" />
      </Formatting>
      <Formatting Mode="Format2">
        <FormatterSettings Range="Range3" Restriction="None" Padding="0" />
      </Formatting>
```

And my class looks like this

```
public class Formatting
{
    [XmlAttribute("Mode")]
    public FormatterType Mode { get; set; }

    public FormatterSettings FormatSettings { get; set; }
}


public class FormatterSettings
{
    [XmlAttribute("Range")]
    public CharacterRange CharRange { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Restriction")]
    public CharacterRangeRestriction RestrictRange { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Padding")]
    public int Padding { get; set; }
}
```

But I have a special formatter that has only one setting so I need the XML  to look like

```
      <Formatting Mode="DateFormatter">
        <FormatterSettings DateFormat="yyyyMMdd" />
      </Formatting>
```

So in that special case my class would be, without the other settings, but I only want one class, for both if that's even possible.

```
public class FormatterSettings
{
    [XmlAttribute("DateFormat")]
    public string DateFormat{ get; set; }

}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
public class FormatterSettings
{
    [XmlAttribute("Range")]
    public CharacterRange CharRange { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Restriction")]
    public CharacterRangeRestriction RestrictRange { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Padding")]
    public int Padding { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("DateFormat")]
    public string DateFormat{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: but then won't I see all 4 attributes in the element?  I only want visible the dateformat attribute when the mode is dateformatter

Comment: it would leave out the attribute if it were null, although something like an int would still be there as 0